# Horizontal crosshairs for multiple series

Tags: highcharts

It seems like when I enable crosshair for the yAxis, only the last series defined get a crosshair. I would like all of them to be crosshaired.

(.. and I would love if they also had the color (or preferably a darker variant) as the series.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an y axis per series, link those additional axes to the first one and define a specific crosshair in each axis - then link series with a specific axis and you will get an seperate customizable crosshair per series.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    yAxis: [{
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      crosshair: {
        width: 2,
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    }, {
      linkedTo: 0,
      crosshair: {
        width: 2,
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      },
      visible: false
    }],

    tooltip: {
      shared: true
    },

    series: [{
        data: data.slice()
    }, {
      yAxis: 1,
      data: data.reverse()
    }]
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/absuLu6h/

Comment: This works, but how do you handle the case where the second y axis has values that are not in range of the first y axis? As an example,  I forked the original example to http://jsfiddle.net/j5rpa5fr/ . The second series has values out of range of the first and the results are not so pleasing.

Comment: The second axis is linked to the first, so the second axis have the same extremes as the first one. You can disable linking and both axes will have proper extremes according to the series - http://jsfiddle.net/j5rpa5fr/1/

Comment: I understand that I can unlink to the first axis, but linking to the first axis was the whole point of the exercise.

In your exercise, the second graph does not match the yaxis  of the first graph and so the the way the two graphs overlay each other doesn't make numerical sense (considering we only one to show one y axis label)