# In Highcharts, shared tooltips ruin crosshairs on the Y axis

Tags: highcharts

I have this issue, where I want a shared and custom-formatted tooltip on a Highcharts chart, but at the same time I want the crosshairs to work.

There is no issue on the x axis, but the on the y, it does not follow the pointer.

Any suggestions?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },

  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },

  yAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },

  series: [
    {
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    },
    {
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].reverse()
    }
  ],

  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  }
});
```

[1st JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/344nLogb/)

**UPDATE:**

Based on the comments given under this post, I've updated the issue.

Now, I have some compromise: I have two crosshairs on the y axis (or, exactly as many as many series item I have...)

The issue is, that if I link the axis options to the 0th option, the scale will be wrong. If I don't (and I don't have an example for that, but you can delete the line and run again), the two series will be at different scales, but since the second option is hidden, the whole think is just a mess.

And if I don't link the options to the 0th item, the crosshairs will not work again...

Any idea for this?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },

  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },

  yAxis: [
    {
      crosshair: true
    },
    {
      linkedTo: 0, // delete me and run again
      crosshair: true,
      visible: false
    }
  ],

  series: [
    {
      yAxis: 0,
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    },
    {
      yAxis: 1,
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].reverse().map(value => value - 5)
    }
  ],

  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  }
});
```

[2nd JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/abcu8opk/)

Comment: this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41750721/3898339) solves your issue??

Comment: In case when there are couple series and tooltip is set to be shared, crosshair displays on the first series. If you want to display crosshair for each series, you can use solution from the topic provided by @Deep3015. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sjrafnaa/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal crosshairs for multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744913/horizontal-crosshairs-for-multiple-series)

Comment: Thanks @Deep3015, It somewhat solves the issue. Core972, I think you linked the same. And you're right. I probably did not search carefully enough!
One last question: in the above solution, there are multiple crosshairs on the y axis and not a single one, on the dot where the mouse is. Is there a solution to that? I mean, having a single crosshair on both axes would be the intended working.

Comment: still i am not able to get  _having a single crosshair on both axes would be the intended working._ what do you mean .although derived sample https://jsfiddle.net/h1Lcm6ap/.

Comment: So.. when you dont have a shared tooltip, a crosshair is only visible if the cursor is close to that given marker. In this case, you actually have both markers drawing a crosshair against the y axis - not considering where the cursor is.

Comment: It is the property of shared tooltip it will behave like that

Comment: Thanks. So.. if you add the solution as a comment I will mark it as the one solving my issue...

Comment: Actually, I have another issue caused by the above solution

Comment: Not sure if I should create a new issue or just update the above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am thinking correctly,your worry is about the negative value.So for the negative value you can assign `min` value to `yAxis` in charts

check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nao67gw/) demo

```
  yAxis: [
    {
      crosshair: true,
      min:-10,
    },
    {
        linkedTo: 0, // delete me and run again
      crosshair: true,
      visible: false
    }
  ],
```

Comment: ppseprus , i missed your comments. I want to mention you that in SO if number participants in comments is more than 2, then you should prefix @ to participant whom you want to message otherwise that participants will not know about the message

Comment: SO only allows one mention per comment, but thanks! : )

Comment: Also, the above solution is somewhat fine. I needed a more dynamic solution, so I use the `tickPositioner: function () { .. }` to generate my own, based on the different mins and maxes on the axes.

Comment: But you solved the original issue, so. thanks a lot! : )